# Numbered propositions

Tags: numbering

I want now and then to set numbered propositions, that can be referred to by
label and repeated.  They should look something like this:

(1) All events have a cause.

Ought I to use the `amsthm` package and `\newtheorem` for this?
If so, I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{prop}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}\label{prop:aec}
    All events have a cause.
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

But that formats the number as `1.` rather than `(1)`.  Can this be changed?
Is there a mechanism for repeating propositions, or do I have to write a macro
myself?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a new theorem style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{user}{}{}{\normalfont}{0pt}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thmnumber{(#2) }}
\theoremstyle{user}
\newtheorem{prop}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}\label{prop:aec}
    All events have a cause.
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

[image]